# Is std::equal_to guaranteed to call operator== by default?

Tags: c++, std, comparison-operators

I had always thought that the standard required the non-specialized template for `std::equal_to<T>` to call `T::operator==`, but I noticed the [description at cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) almost implies it's the other way around; certainly it doesn't mention it as a requirement. I also checked the C++11 draft standard N3337 and couldn't find any guarantees there either.

If you create a class with an `operator==` you'd hope it would get used in all circumstances.

I can't honestly think of a way to implement `std::equal_to` that wouldn't work this way, but am I missing something?

Comment: `std::less` behaves differently than `operator<` in case of pointers.

Comment: The description at cppreference.com is quite clear...

Comment: It is a problem with the description in the page. The description could be improved to be: *Implements a functor calling operator== for type T* (the missing *a functor* is the source of confusion)

Comment: @AlexChamberlain: I don't quite agree with your statement... the sentence *Implements operator== on type T* is a bit misleading

Comment: Ah, missed that. How about now?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain that's better! I was about to make a similar change.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain, I never realized the site was a wiki, or are you an admin of some kind?

Comment: @MarkRansom It's a wiki; that was my first edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is std::equal_to guaranteed to call `operator ==` by default?

**Yes**.

If not specialized, `equal_to`'s call operator will invoke `operator ==`. From Paragraph 20.8.5 of the C++11 Standard:

> 1 The library provides basic function object classes for all of the comparison operators in the language (5.9, 5.10).

```
template <class T> struct equal_to 
{
    bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
    typedef T first_argument_type;
    typedef T second_argument_type;
    typedef bool result_type;
};
```

> 2 **`operator()` returns `x == y`**.

Comment: Gah, you're catching up on my reputation way too quickly!

Comment: @sftrabbit: Not really, it seems to me the difference is always the same 5.2k ;-)

Comment: Naturally I saw that section of the standard, but I guess I was just missing what they were trying to say in plain language.

Comment: @JosephMansfield sorry to say, he surpassed you.  Don't feel bad, it's 10 years later!  My own ranking is slipping, I used to be in the middle of page 5 now it's page 6.

Answer (score 2):

`std::equal_to` is defined as:

```
template <class T> struct equal_to {
  bool operator()(const T& x, const T& y) const;
  typedef T first_argument_type;
  typedef T second_argument_type;
  typedef bool result_type;
};
```

> `operator()` returns `x == y`.

So yes, if `T` is a class type with an `operator==` overload defined for it as the left operand, it will be used.