# passing a function as an argument to a method c++

Tags: c++, overloading

After searching the forum for an answer I cannot seem to resolve this issue.

For pedagogical purposes I'm creating a (template) linked list class. My class has the following method:

```
template <typename E>
bool List<E>::hasValue(E value, bool (*fn)(E, E)){
    bool hasValue = false;
    node* c = head;
    while (true) {
        if (c->value == value) {
            hasValue = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (c->next != 0) {
            c = c->next;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }
    return hasValue;
}
```

I want `bool (*fn)(E, E)` to be any overloaded operator== defined by the user like so:

```
struct record {
    string name;
    int age;
};

bool operator==(const record& r1, const record& r2) {
    bool result = false;
    if (r1.name == r2.name && r1.age == r2.age) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

however if i call `list.hasValue({"duder", 20}, operator==)` Xcode reports:

> No matching member function for call to 'hasValue'

I can't seem to find any online explanation of why this is occurring.

Comment: Your `operator==` code is pretty convoluted. You could (and should) simply use `return r1.name == r2.name && r1.age == r2.age;`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

don't you want something like

```
 if ((*fn)(c->value,value)) {...}
```

also , I suggest passing the arguments as const references.

Also, since this is a template function , are you sure you're defining the function in the same header file it's declared?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic comparator concept:

```
template <typename E, typename Comp>
bool List<E>::hasValue(E value, Comp fn) { ... }
```

this lets you avoid the need to specify the function signature (which really gains you nothing).

Then you can call it as:

```
list.hasValue(record{"duder", 20}, std::equal_to<record>());
```

where [`std::equal_to`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/equal_to) is imported from [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional). This functor [will call `operator==`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15122462/493122) if it exists.

---

In fact I would also recommend, for semantic purposes, to automatically default to using `std::equal_to` in your `hasValue` definition if the comparator is not explicitly defined:

```
template <typename E, typename Comp = std::equal_to<E>>
bool List<E>::hasValue(E value, Comp fn = {}) { ... }
```